# Unsupported image object while using Tesseract

Tags: python-3.7, python-tesseract

When I run this code I'm getting the following error:

pytesseract.pytesseract.tessaract_cmd = r'F:\Tesseract-OCR\tesseract.exe'
video_capture = cv2.VideoCapture(0)

while True:
frame = video_capture.read()
if frame is None:
break

```
text = pytesseract.image_to_string(frame, lang="eng_fast", config="--psm 7")
print(int(len("len of text is: ", text)))
print(text)

cv2.imshow('Video', frame)
if waitKey(1) & 0xff == ord('q'):
    break
```

video_capture.release()
cv2.destroyAllwindows()

TypeError: "Unsupported image object".
Error is in the "text" line.
Can someone help

Answer (score 1):

`video_capture.read` method return two variables, as stated [here](https://docs.opencv.org/master/dd/d43/tutorial_py_video_display.html):

- `ret` if the current captures frame read correctly
- `frame`: Current frame

By saying:

```py
frame = video_capture.read()
```

Your `frame` variables containes: `ret` and `frame`

If you are sure all frames return correctly, use

```py
_, frame = video_capture.read()
```

Otherwise:

```py
ret, frame = video_capture.read()
```

Partial-Code:

---

```py
video_capture = cv2.VideoCapture(0)

while True:
    ret, frame = video_capture.read() 
    .
    .
```

Comment: I tried " _, frame" but now I'm getting error as teserract not installed ot not in path. But the path given is correct. Please suggest what to do. Thank you.

Comment: That depends the location of your tesseract. Maybe you should check whether is it in the `F` folder? or does your `F` path contains `Tesseract-OCR` folder?

Comment: It is the F path which contains Tesseract-OCR folder inside which tesseract.exe is present.

Comment: I think you accidentally mistyped the `pytesseract.pytesseract.tesseract_cmd`. In your code it is `tessaract_cmd`.

Comment: Yeah there was a spelling mistake. Thank you So much.